# Odoo retrieve if create is called directly from selection list

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Is there any way to know if create method is called directly from selection list field?

I have to extend create method (The context not contains this information).
[image]

Comment: When we write on Many2one field, in backend, their will be two method calls. 1. name_get() and 2. name_search() so we need to track that methods. And You may pass context on Partner field via .xml file.

Comment: You can restart Odoo server with "--log-level=debug_rpc" option. It will list out all methods in the log which will be called during your activities in Odoo.